# How to put big brackets around minipage

Tags: minipage, brackets

I have this bit in my document and I would like to put big brackets on either side to show it is not part of the main development. However, I have no idea how to do such a thing. Any help is welcomed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
    \begin{equation*}
        \frac{\partial}{\partial V}[x\text{ln}(x)] = -\frac{x}{V}(\text{ln}(x) + 1)
    \end{equation*}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
    \begin{equation*}
        \frac{\partial}{\partial V}[(1-x)\text{ln}(1-x)] = -\frac{x}{V}(\text{ln}(1-x) + 1)
    \end{equation*}
\end{minipage}%
\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your posting to make the sample code minimally compilable. This sample code places the `minipage` environments next to each other. Should the brackets go around both minipages, just the one on the left, or just the one on the right. Please advise.

Comment: Thank you. It should go around both minipages

Comment: Then why 2 minipages? You need only one.

Comment: Off-topic: Please don't write `\text{ln}`; instead, do please write `\ln`. Because the macro has `math-op` status, the horizontal spaceing around it will be better than for `\text{ln}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need a single `minipage`. You don't need two separate `equation*` environments either.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'equation*' environment
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\left[
 \frac{\partial}{\partial V}[x\ln(x)] 
 = -\frac{x}{V}(\ln(x) + 1)
\qquad
 \frac{\partial}{\partial V}[(1-x)\ln(1-x)] 
 = -\frac{x}{V}(\ln(1-x) + 1)
\right]
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think it's unlikely that both equations fit in a single line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]
\[
\left[\quad
  \begin{gathered}
  \frac{\partial}{\partial V}[x\log(x)] = -\frac{x}{V}(\log(x) + 1)
  \\
  \frac{\partial}{\partial V}[(1-x)\log(1-x)] = -\frac{x}{V}(\log(1-x) + 1)
  \end{gathered}
\quad\right]
\]
\lipsum[2][1-4]

\end{document}
```

The `\quad` spaces should clearly show that this is not a matrix.

[image]

**Note.** `\text{ln}` is wrong and should be `\log` (part of my personal campaign to eradicate abominable pieces of notation from mathematics, such as `\ln` and `\sin^{-1}`). Feel free to replace `\log` with the abomination.

Comment: Thank you for the note. Although I don't see why is `\ln` wrong ? I don't know if it's an universal thing but in France we use `ln` for base e and `log` for base 10 which is why I used ln.

Comment: @Galou For a few centuries, mathematicians have used “log” for the natural logarithm and maybe “Log” for the decimal. Then a bunch of engineers came up with the idea that “ln” is better.

Answer (score 0):

You need only a minipage, but a  bit wider:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[\left[
\begin{minipage}{0.6\linewidth}
\vspace{1ex}
    \begin{equation*}
        \frac{\partial}{\partial V}[x\text{ln}(x)] = -\frac{x}{V}(\text{ln}(x) + 1)
    \end{equation*}
    \begin{equation*}
        \frac{\partial}{\partial V}[(1-x)\text{ln}(1-x)] = -\frac{x}{V}(\text{ln}(1-x) + 1)
    \end{equation*}
\vspace{-1ex}
\end{minipage}
\right]\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, no. I'd also use two lines, but like `\[\left[ \begin{gathered} <first> \\ <second>\end{gathered}\right]\]`. Never (well, hardly ever) use two consecutive display environments.